# Store multiple matplotlib figures in a dictionary and use keys to display them / modify them at will?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that generates a plot from data I have read in. The goal is to be able to open multiple plot windows, each with a unique name, and then allow other functions to alter them at will (updating the data in them, changing colors, etc.), or to re-open plots that have been closed.

What I have tried to do is this:

1) Define a class, workspace, that has an attribute Figures that is a dictionary. I intend to assign my figures to unique keys in this dictionary.

2) Now, I generate a figure, and then save it into the WS.Figures dictionary.

3) Simplest use case, the user closes the figure and wants to re-open it, without having to go through make_plot() again. (My actual function has far, far, more complexity in the plotting - it's a pain to re-create each time manually). So I tried to write the following, which does absolutely nothing, apparently.

```
class WorkSpace(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.Figures = {}

        return  

WS = WorkSpace()

def make_plot(x_data,y_data,name):

    plt.ion()

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.plot(x_data,y_data)

    fig.canvas.draw()   

    WS.Figures[name] = fig

    return  

def replot(name):

    WS.Figures[name].canvas.draw()

            return
```

My thinking here was that WS.Figures[name] would hold an identical copy of fig from make_plot() and so I'd just need to issue the same command to make it appear.

I was hoping this would be the absolute easiest thing to do, and that I could then use that dictionary key to refer to the plot, update axes, etc. whenever I needed. But if I can't even replot it...

Comment: If a pyplot figure is closed it is closed. It cannot be reactivated via pyplot. You may write you custom GUI, that would create new window with the figure restored from memory. However, it seems much easier to just call make_plot again.

Comment: So maybe then instead I should somehow be storing 100% of the arguments needed to call make_plot again?  The problem is that make_plot actually takes a bajillion arguments, and I don't want the user to have to retype that every time they make a plot.  That also doesn't solve the problem of having two open figures at once and being able to point functions at them individually to modify/update them, though.  Unless that is also impossible and you can only ever modify the active figure?

Comment: If you could store the arguments, `make_plot(**kwargs)` takes like `self.lastkw = kwargs` (if make_plot was a method of some class), and later in `replot(**kwargs)` update like `self.lastkw.update(kwargs); make_plot(**self.lastkw)` or similar. I don't understand the problem of having more than one figure open. If that is part of this question, make it part of the question.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the multiple figures is already part of the question.  The entire goal here is to find a way to store the plots somewhere and be able to refer to them by a name, so that I can call a function I wrote to change an open figure or to make a figure again that I already had open, not just the active open figure.  My attempt here was to do that, and I thought the easiest test of my method was just to try to reopen a closed figure, but that didn't work, so I was trying to figure out why.

Comment: You can `pickle` a figure. Maybe that comes closest to what you want to do?

Comment: I'd looked at that initially, yes, but decided I didn't want to be generating extra files.  I'm trying to run everything inside a single iPython instance.

Comment: Did you try just minimizing rather than closing the figures, using the figure manager (the minimization call is different for different backends)?